# How to run a cron entry periodically?

Tags: downloads, cron, automation, date, filename

I have a line of script that works through terminal and works through `cron` to run one time: it downloads a file from the internet and saves it in a specific place named as the date it was found:

```
cd /media/path/to/folder && wget "http://www.web/address/name.gif" && mv name.gif "$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_T%H%M')"
```

I put this together one bit at a time, as I'm new to Ubuntu, then put it together in terminal, then ran it successfully as a one time task, entered in the "Scheduled Tasks" window.  When I add it through `cron` with `crontab -e` to run on the first minute of every hour as:
`1 * * * * cd ...`
It ran once but didn't repeat.

When I open it in "Scheduled Tasks" it says:

> Your command contains one or more of the character %, this is special
>   for cron and cannot be used with Gnome-schedule ....

I don't understand this error, since I can use the same script with the one-time task in Scheduled Tasks without problem.
Any advice on the script error?  Knowledge of why it won't repeat?  Simplifications to script?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you able to write it as a bash script, and then call taht from cron?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make archive every minute using "crontab"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/770850/make-archive-every-minute-using-crontab)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the % symbols like so:

`date +\%Y_\%m`

Comment: Switching to the \%Y format made it work!  Thanks!