# Make a new archive once per minute using "crontab"

Tags: cron, tar

I am trying to make a `crontab` that makes a new `.tar` file each minute every business day by using the following code:

```
*/1 * * * 1,2,3,4,5 tar -cf /home/user/Archiv/$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M").tar /home/user/Textverarbeitung/ -P
```

This doesn't work. Why?

Comment: I can't stop reading the title as "Make **every archive minute** using crontab" (minute as in small) because the article is missing (not OP's fault), so I'm fixing it.

Comment: Why would you use `*/1`? Isn't that the same as just `*`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`cron` treats `%` as newlines. You need to use escape it i.e. use `\%` to get literal `%` as used in `date`.

So you need:

```
date +"\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M"
```

Or you can use a script and use all the commands in the script and call the script from `crontab`.

From `man 5 crontab`:

> Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\),
>   will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first
>   % will be sent to the command as standard input. There is no way to
>   split  a  single  command  line  onto  multiple lines, like the
>   shell's trailing "\".

Answer (score 4):

Use `\%` instead of `%` - cron uses `%` as a newline.